# Vim: Remap dollar sign in insert mode

Tags: vim

Consider the following line in my `.vimrc`:

`autocmd Filetype tex inoremap <buffer> $ $$^[i`

The aim is to insert two dollar signs in TeX files when I type one in insert mode, similar to how auto-closing brackets works.

However, whenever I open a TeX file, Vim just prints the message `No mapping found`. I've also tried to escape the dollar sign (`... inoremap \$ $$^[i`), but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Why `$$^[i` instead of `$$`?

Comment: @SibiCoder The `^[i` is to place the cursor between the dollar signs (`^[` being `ESC`).

Comment: btw, you can write `<esc>` instead of `^[`, easier to understand and to write

Comment: @Elisha I didn't know that, it is certainly clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The space between the dollar signs was a non-breaking space (typing `$` requires pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on my keyboard, which combined with space produces a non-breaking space on Unix). Changing it to a regular space fixed the issue.

Apparently I had made the same mistake several times, as I've re-typed the command in various places around my configuration when trying to figure out the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that your vim recognize your `tex` files as `plaintex` filetype.
you should add the line

`let g:tex_flavor = "latex"`

to your `.vimrc` file to make it recognize `tex` files as TeX.

so, I believe you want to add those lines to your `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
autocmd Filetype tex inoremap <buffer> $ $$^[i
```

you can find more information about this issue here:
https://superuser.com/questions/208177/vim-and-tex-filetypes-plaintex-vs-tex

Comment: This isn't the case, as I have the `g:latex_flavor` setting in my `.vimrc` already. The message `No mapping found` also suggests that the command gets executed.